# Ошибка в записи двоичного файл (binary file)

Tags: python, кодировка, binary, wav

Моя цель перезаписать файл расширения `wav` в двоичный файл (`binary file/file.bin`). Для кодирования я пользуюсь теорией квантования (создания шага квантования...).

Код реализует функцию кодирования. Элементы, которые меняются - это сам трек, число битов и цель (т.е, в какой файл я записываю, в моем случае это `bin`).

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
import pickle

def enc(track, n, target):
    rate, data = wav.read(track)
    qStep = (float(np.max(data)) - float(np.min(data)))/(2**n-1)
    dataQuant = np.round(data/(qStep))*qStep
    b = open(target, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, b, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    b.close()
```

Если я запускаю ее как: `enc('track.wav', 16, 'enс.bin')`, то получаю двоичный файл, который похож по размеру с треком, что думаю верно, так как трек 16 бит.

Если запускаю: `enc('track.wav', 8, 'enс8.bin')`, т.е, если хочу перекодировать в 8 бит, то получаю файл схожий по размеру с `enс.bin`, хотя он должен быть в 2 раза меньше по размеру.

Использую один и тот же трек.

Как мне исправить свою ошибку?

**Новая задача**

Хочу перезаписать свой файл обратно,т.е с формата bin в wav.
Для этого прописываю:

```
b = open(filename,"rb")
data= pickle.load(b)
b.close()
scipy.io.wavfile.write(str.replace(filename,".bin","_decoded.wav"), 44100, data)
```

Получаю "ужасный" трек при декодирование из 8 бит файла. Как исправить?

Comment: Говорить об ошибке можно только если файлы по размеру не "похожи", а в точности совпадают... У вас же файлы заново создаются каждый раз?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, для функции я использую одинаковый трек(16 бит) и кодирую его в 16 бит или 8 бит файл. При кодированиии в 8 бит двоичный файл (binary file/ enc.bin) должен создаться файл меньше 16 бит

Comment: @LenaPark а создается файл во сколько байт? Только не "похоже", а точно. Может, и ошибки-то нет?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, мой файл размером в 4,7 мб, в точности как размер трека. Трек 4,,7 мб и 16 бит, если я его перекодирую  в 8 бит, разве файл 8 бит не должен быть меньше?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, то, что он должен меньше, уже проверяла. Используя ' `scaled =np.array(data/255,dtype='int8')`

Comment: @LenaPark, а где вы изменяете тип данных (dtype)? Если вы его не меняете, то и размер на диске не поменятся - `123` и `10**10` - занимают одинаковое к-во памяти если они одного типа...

Comment: @MaxU, имеете в виду, что мне нужно прям прописать, что записываю такой тип данных (16 бит или 8 бит)?

Comment: @MaxU, в шаге квантовая я указываю n-количество битов. 2^(n-1). если у меня 16 бит,

Comment: @LenaPark, вам где-то (перед записью) надо изменить тип данных: `dataQuant = dataQuant.astype(np.int16)` и потом записывать в файл не исходный массив `data`, а измененный `dataQuant`

Comment: @LenaPark, я вам уже писал выше, что разделив все значения матрицы на какое-либо число вы не уменьшите объем занимаемый этой матрицей в памяти/на диске

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
qStep = (float(np.max(data)) - float(np.min(data)))/(2**(n-1))
precision = n // 8 * 8
dataQuant = np.array(np.round(data/(qStep))*qStep, dtype='int{}'.format(precision))

b = open(target, 'wb')
pickle.dump(dataQuant, b, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
```

Comment: что означает ваша строчка precision = n // 8 * 8?